# Who discovered the famous combinatorial intepretation of Eulerian numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

Eulerian numbers $A(n, k)$ were discovered by Euler in 1755 in his work *Institutiones calculi differentialis.* In combinatorics, they count the number permutations of the numbers 1 to $n$ with exactly $k$ ascents.

I do not find any further information about the develop of Eulerian numbers from 1755 to now (for example I do not find any information about who discovered the combinatorial intepretation).

Does anyone have these informations? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what it's worth ([Tingyao Xiong, Hung-Ping Tsao, Jonathan I. Hall, "General Eulerian Numbers and Eulerian Polynomials", Journal of Mathematics, vol. 2013, Article ID 629132, 9 pages, 2013. https://doi.org/10.1155/2013/629132](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jmath/2013/629132/)):

> The following combinatorial definition of Eulerian numbers was
> discovered by Riordan in the 1950s.

Answer (score 2):

Richard Stanley, in his book *Enumerative Combinatorics*, Volume I, writes that "the first written statement connecting Eulerian numbers with descents seems to have been by Carlitz and Riordan in 1953." The reference is to the paper, [Congruences for Eulerian numbers](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-53-02033-X), *Duke Math. J.* 20 (1953), 339–343. They write:

> This is associated with a game of patience played with deck of cards of arbitrary specification, with cards dealt into a single pack so long as they are not falling and a new pack started for every fall; the problem is to determine the number of ways of dealing $s$ packs. When the deck is of cards numbered $1$ to $k$, the answer is given by numbers $A_{ks}$.

Though you didn't ask about this specifically, Stanley also mentions that Laplace (1812) already knew that Eulerian numbers measure the volume of diagonal slices of a hypercube. See [An asymptotic distribution theory for Eulerian recurrences with applications](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aam.2019.101960) by Hwang et al. for more information.